# Where do I ask a question about programming macros in Word?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Programming suggests SO, but Word Macros suggest SuperUser.

I want to make some custom dialog boxes that would display specific content on a click in a word doc--think of a hyperlink that opens a dialog box instead of a web page--and need to ask some questions. Would that fall more into a programming or a superuser question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the question involves code and writing code, it belongs on Stack Overflow.

If it is a generic question about using Macros and general information about programming macros (without any code), then Super User could indeed be the right site.